# Browser tab close detect in gwt

Tags: javascript, gwt, browser, internet-explorer-7

I am developing a gwt application and I am going to support only for ie7. Now I have a requirement to detect browser tab close event.I have tried Window.addWindowClosingHandler(...) . But this is getting fired when we click any url in the page or refresh. I just want to detect only browser close event. I dont want to capture any other event like browser refresh, url click. Is there any way to detect only that.

Answer (score 1):

it should work

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {

        @Override
        public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
            Window.alert("bye bye beautiful");

        }
    });
```

**[EDIT]** 
or maybe you search `onBrowserEvent();` and detect which event user do

```
public void onBrowserEvent(Event event)
    {
        switch (DOM.eventGetType(event))
        Event.onClick
        Event.onPaste
        Event.onLoad
```

Comment: Hi Hilal, Thanks for the answer. Actually I want to identify how the close event is fired. I want to know whether user has clicked browser close or refresh button or some hypherlink in the page. Based on that I want to do something.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't expose what caused the page to get closed, so GWT unfortunately cannot expose this information.

The underlying JavaScript event is the [onbeforeunload](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+onbeforeunload) event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use session cookies, as described in the selected answer of this question:
[GWT WindowClosingHandler firing on Browser refresh too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898144/gwt-windowclosinghandler-firing-on-browser-refresh-too)